# INSERT statement is changing integers to null values

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm creating a table with 3 million rows of data and 9 columns. 
I am using the following syntax to insert my data.

```
INSERT INTO myTable
( column1
  column2
  column3
  ...
  column11
  problemColumn
)

Select
<exampleQuery>
```

1 column (which I will refer to as **problemColumn**) inserts 1.2 million null values into this table

When I run **exampleQuery** on its own (not inserting it into the table), **problemColumn** returns 0 null values.

- problemColumn is correctly defined as an integer when the table is created
- problemColumn has 300,000 distinct values. Each value appears in the table at least once, which means that it can't be an issue of a poorly-formatted value
- There is no obvious pattern of values being systematically deleted

**Edit: Some additional clarifications:**

- There are no calculations or joins done on **problemColumn**. I am simply selecting that variable from another table
- **problemColumn** is an integer in the source table, so it is not an issue of a mismatched variable type

Could this be an issue with the size of the table in the database? I cannot comprehend why a query would fundamentally change from an insert statement.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same datatype on both sides?  If it's an integer in your target table, what happens if you cast it to integer in your select?

Comment: You need to show the actual SQL, is there any calculation done on `problemColumn`?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and an example of the actual queries you are running that provide both the correct and incorrect results? Working blind makes it hard to provide a good answer (or, indeed, an answer at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely cause (I've done it myself) is fat fingers - the column you're inserting is in the wrong position. Hard to verify without seeing the actual code, but it might be as simple as:

```
insert into table 
(column1, 
column2)
select
(column2, 
column1)
from somewhere
```

Second possibility - there's a trigger on the destination table, which is changing the data. One of the many reasons I hate triggers.

I don't know Teradata, but the point of an RDBMS is to be able to handle exactly this scenario, so it's very unlikely it's anything to do with the size. To verify this, please try to limit the query to 1 result, and see what happens.

If that doesn't work, please convert the results of that query into an insert statement using "values"

```
INSERT INTO myTable
( column1
  column2
  column3
  ...
  column11
  problemColumn
)
values
(....)
```

Comment: Your first solution solved my problem. The order of variables in the insert statement did not match the order of the variables in the query. However, I am curious as to why only _some_ of the values were affected. I would expect every value to be null.